# 406 error when I try and submit http:// in my database

Tags: php, http

I'm not sure why this is happening. First time ever happen to me. I noticed when I would be anything that had http:// in my textarea field and submited it I would get a 406 error saying:

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /server/uploadFail.php could not be found on this server.
Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string so isn't that suppose to prevent mysql injections? I'm a little confused how to go about fixing this. heres my code:

```
                $short_des = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['leaveDesTxt']);

             $sql = "INSERT INTO fail_images(`user_id`,`file_name`,`date_submited`,`time_submited`,`ip_addr`,`viewable`,`short_des`) VALUES ('$user_id','$file_name','$date','$time','$ip','1','$short_des')";

             mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die($sql .' : ' . mysqli_error($conn));

             mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: 406 is an error related to a web-server configuration

Comment: So there is nothing I can actually do in my code to prevent that error?

Comment: exactly. looks like it's sort of security facility in action

Comment: Well turning off Mod_security wouldn't be a good idea either. Surely there is a good work around to prevent this type of error from happening.

Comment: Nobody else has any ideas and work arounds?